# Summation in subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

A bit of a beginner question, but I'm currently working on routing and travelling salesman problem and a bit confused. Currently I have these two constraints in my model, but what is the mathemathical difference between these two?

1. $$\sum_{i \in V}x_i,_j = 1 \ for  \ all \ {j \in V}$$
2. $$\sum_{j \in V}x_i,_j = 1 \ for  \ all \ {i \in V}$$

Which constraint sums up the rows and which constraint sums up the columns?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2601399/290189

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix $X = (x_{i,j})_{i,j \in V}$. The first expression says that, for every column (which are indexed by $j \in V$), the sum of its elements is 1. In other words, the $j$-column is fixed and the row index $i$ runs: so it's a sum over a column. The second expression is the same but for every row.

Comment: Thank you! Very clear answer